# question mark over checkbox

Tags: asp.net

I am designing a checkbox

When I run the application, and when I bring the mouse over the text of Checkbox, the mouse pointer is getting changed. Along with the pointer a question mark is coming. But there is no problem with the functionality. I am able check or uncheck the checkbox and able to submit and do all the opertions. The only problem is When i bring the mouse over the text of the checkbox, the question mark is appearing. How to solve it? What could be the Problem? Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly something which configured in the stylesheet of the application. It is possible to define the cursor for a certain element in your style sheet. You should look into your stylesheets (CSS files) and check if you can find code like:

`cursor: help`

You should also check if this is happening in all browsers. Another option to debug this issue is to use Firefox + Firebug and see what styles are associated with the checkbox to see where the odd cursor is coming from.